# Is there a standard way in iOS 5 to do delete confirmation like in Contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a standard way in iOS 5 to show delete confirmation as in this screenshot?

If there is no standard way, any solution will be good.

[image: delete confirmation]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a `UIActionSheet` with the destructive button set. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

e.g.

```
// Create the action sheet
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

...

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex) {
        // Do the delete
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8. Apple's documentation recommends that you use `UIAlertController` instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIActionSheet as following.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" delegate:aDelegate cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[actionSheet showFromRect:aRect inView:aView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8. Instead, use [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) with a preferred style of `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.

```
// Create a new alert, with an (optional) title and message
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                               message:nil
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


// When style is set to UIAlertActionStyleDestructive, the button appears with red text
UIAlertAction* deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {                                     
                                                          // ========
                                                          // Perform your delete operation here...
                                                          // ========
                                                      }];


// This cancel action will appear separated from the rest of the items
UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];


// Add the actions to the alert
[alert addAction:deleteAction];
[alert addAction:cancelAction];

// Present the sheet.
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I usually omit the title and message fields for delete confirmations, because I find that the built-in applications on iOS (like Contacts, Messages, Mail, etc) don't typically use those fields. The button speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of that UI component: [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIActionSheetDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html)